# Animate the fading of an image with Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, function, fadein

I currently have the following code to add an overlay onto an image when you hover over it:

```
<script>
    function toggleOverlay(name, newState){
        var element = 'imgOverlay' + name;
        var newDisplay

        if (newState == 0) {newDisplay = 'none'}
        if (newState == 1) {newDisplay = 'block'}          

        document.getElementById(element).style.display = newDisplay;
        //document.getElementById(element).style.z-index = '5';
    }

    function clearOverlays(){
        toggleOverlay('SteBes',0);
        toggleOverlay('VicGun',0);
        toggleOverlay('SteFry',0);
        toggleOverlay('DomSag',0);
        toggleOverlay('DenCro',0);
        //toggleOverlay('UnkOne',0);
        //toggleOverlay('UnkTwo',0);
        toggleOverlay('SteWoz',0);
    }
</script>
```

How can I fade in the overlay as at the moment it just changes suddenly?

Thanks.

Comment: you should be using jquery, which can easily achieve so  by `show` and `hide`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use JQuery? you can do that out of the box.

Comment: how can I do this via jQuery? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is Javascript example with CSS3

http://jsfiddle.net/sLNqm/

Please go to following link there are jquery sample examples

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

```
$(document.body).click(function () {
  $("#DivName").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: I tried `$(element).hide().fadeIn(4000);`, but that didn't work at all for me